# can't iterate over collection of divs using watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I need to iterate over collection of divs, click each div and then click back div and do it again.

This is the link to site http://services.tvzavr.ru/alliance/index.html
On this site I need to open 'Фильмы' section and then iterate over divs collection. Meaning click each item, then page opens, then click back and then do it again for all elements in the collection.

This is the link to the site http://services.tvzavr.ru/alliance/index.html

In my step  I do this

`@browser.divs(:class => 'carousel-lst-itm nav-itm').each do |itm|
    itm.when_present.click 
    @browser.div(:class => 'ftr-nav-return btn btn-blue nav-   itm').when_present.click
    sleep 1
  end`

But it works only for first item in the collection, and then it stops with timeout error

timed out after 90 seconds, waiting for {:element=>#} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)

I expected it iterate over collection of divs.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/unknownobjectexception-with-element-not-found-in-the-cache-message/

```
    @browser.divs(:class => 'carousel-lst-itm-cover').each_with_index do |_, i|
   @browser.div(:class => 'carousel-lst-itm-cover', index: i).when_present.click
    sleep 1
    if @browser.div(:class => 'video-itm-price').present? 
      puts @browser.div(:class => 'video-itm-price').text
      break
    else 
      @browser.i(:class => 'i-return').when_present.click
      break if i == 10
    end
    sleep 1
  end
```